# Visual Studio 2010 hangs when running Selenium as Pre-Build event

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, selenium, dos, pre-build-event

I have created a bat file which calls selenium server called run-selenium-server.bat which has:

```
java -jar D:\temp\selenium-server\selenium-server.jar
```

Also I have added in my project properties "Build Events" the pre-build event command line:

```
"$(SolutionDir)..\references\selenium-server\run-selenium-server.bat"
```

The path is correct but when I build the project: Visual Studio 2010 just hangs and I have to open Process Explorer to kill java process.

I noticed Output window is showing the pre-build command output. Is there a way to run this bat file as a separate DOS process directly from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
call "$(SolutionDir)..\references\selenium-server\run-selenium-server.bat"
```

This is noted on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). Also note that it's probably best to start the java.exe using the `start` command like so:

```
start java -jar D:\temp\selenium-server\selenium-server.jar
```